# How to get similar functionality to RStudio in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, data-science

I normally use **RStudio** to do data science work. I load the datasets, and then write and try new code line by line, changing parameters, exploring the data, and executing small chunks at a time.
I'm currently using **PyCharm** for a project in Python, and it seems to be geared to software development, running and debugging entire scripts from start to finish, which is incredibly slow and frustrating when used to the RStudio mode.

Is it possible to have a similar data science environment to RStudio is it better to change tool to something else?

Comment: It is more usual to do this kind of exploratory work in a (Jupyter) notebook.  Jupyter Lab combines such a notebook with some other functionality to make it some kind of IDE - notebook hybrid.  I would check those out.  You might also be happy using the iPython terminal since you seem to want a REPL.

Comment: You have Spyder as a close alternative to Rstudio. The only issue I found with it is you can't run HTML in the IPython console. For this I use JupyterLab. There is a way to set up JupyterLab to link a script to a console. 
It's not as AMAZING as Rstudio is but it's better than the other alternatives I've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run code line-by-line you could try this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11945-python-smart-execute.

If you want to change the default hotkey from "Ctrl+Shift+A" to default RStudio "Ctrl + Enter" you could do that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44wZC.png).

Also, here's a ticket about merging the plugin into PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38919.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable `"Scientific Mode"` in PyCharm. In this mode all code is executed inside the same interactive Python Console, all plots and tabular data are shown in a separate panel, there is a separate panel with Documentation. Also it supports code cells execution (code blocks inside *.py file separated by `#%%`), current line/file execution in Python Console (available in the context menu in the editor).

The full description is available here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html

Comment: Only in PyCharm pro, but this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!